# Using the Angular inject function with a APP_INITIALIZER

Tags: angular, typescript, dependency-injection, factory, app-initializer

With Ivy, Angular introduced the nice [`inject` function](https://angular.io/api/core/inject).
[According to the documentation](https://angular.io/api/core/inject#usage-notes) the function can be used "from a provider's factory" accompanied with the following example:

```js
providers: [
  {
    provide: Car,
    useFactory: () => {
      // OK: a class factory
      const engine = inject(Engine);
      return new Car(engine);
    }
  }
]
```

This makes me believe that I can now convert my old `APP_INITIALIZER`s:

```js
providers: [
  {
    provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
    useFactory: (engine: Engine) => () => engine.start(),
    deps: [Engine],
    multi: true
  }
]
```

using the `inject` function to something simpler like this:

```js
providers: [
  {
    provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
    useFactory: () => () => inject(Engine).start(),
    multi: true
  }
]
```

This fails, however, giving me the following error message:

> Error: NG0203: inject() must be called from an injection context such as a constructor, a factory function, a field initializer, or a function used with `EnvironmentInjector#runInContext`.

Is it no longer a factory context, when using `APP_INITIALIZER`? Or what is the problem here?

Comment: Is Engine a service or what?
inject() looks through Environment Injection Hierarchy for the dependencies. Are you sure Engine is provided at this level?

Comment: Like in the documentation example, `Engine` is something that can be injected. Exactly what isn't important, but yes, it could be a service. The important thing is that it can be injected, but trying to do it with `inject` fails when using `APP_INITIALIZER`. I've changed the example slightly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a missing feature, context exists only in the top level function.

This is working example:

```
providers: [
  {
    provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
    useFactory: () => {
      const engine = inject(Engine);
      return () => engine.start();
    },
    multi: true
  }
]
```

Or

```
providers: [
  {
    provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
    useFactory: () => {
      inject(Engine).start();
      return () => {};
    },
    multi: true
  }
]
```

Comment: Ah, that's it! What a wicked quirk.